# Creating and showing complex JSON object dynamically using VueJS component and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, recursion

I am developing a `Vuejs` application within which I have a field `extension`. For this field, users can provide the values and this field expands dynamically (both vertically and horizontally) based on the user-provided values.

I am using the recursive component `ExtensionComponent` to display and store the values. But it's not working as expected for me.

The field name `extensions` displays, initially an `Add Extension`. With on click of the button, a  `bootstrap modal` will be displayed which has 3 fields: `namespace (text)`, `localname (text)`, `datatype(dropdown: string/complex)`. If the `datatype` is `string` then a `simple text field` will be displayed. However, if the `datatype` is `complex` then `another button` should be displayed and on click of the button again the `same bootstrap modal` is displayed with fields and the process continues. So the created `JSON` based on this will expand horizontally and vertically.

I am able to create the `Vue component` to show the recursive data but I am a bit confused about the addition of the values to `extensionList` array dynamically. Can someone please help me with this issue?

Following is my `Test.vue` page which will display the `Extensions` and `Add Button`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span>Extensions</span>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="createExtensions">
      Add Another
    </button>

    <ExtensionComponent :extension-list="$store.state.extensionList" />
    <TestModal v-if="$store.state.showModal" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import TestModal from '@/components/TestModal.vue'

export default {
  computed: {
    TestModal
  },
  methods: {
    // Method to create extensions and add
    createExtensions () {
      this.$store.commit('toggleExtensionModal')
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Following is my Bootstrap modal (`TestModal.vue`) which will be displayed whenever `Add Another` button is clicked (initially and for complex):

```
<template>
  <b-modal
    id="Extension"
    title="Add Another Element"
    size="lg"
    width="100%"
    :visible="$store.state.showModal"
  >
    <b-form id="AddExtension" @submit.prevent="submitExtension">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Namespace URI:</label>
        <input
          v-model="extension.namespace"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          required
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Local Name:</label>
        <input
          v-model="extension.localName"
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          required
        >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label
          for="AddExtensionDataType"
          class="col-form-label"
        >Data Type:</label>
        <b-form-select v-model="extension.dataType" class="form-control">
          <b-form-select-option value="string">
            String
          </b-form-select-option>
          <b-form-select-option value="complex">
            Complex
          </b-form-select-option>
        </b-form-select>
      </div>
    </b-form>
    <template #modal-footer="{ cancel }">
      <b-btn @click="cancel">
        Cancel
      </b-btn>
      <b-btn variant="primary" type="submit" form="AddExtension">
        OK
      </b-btn>
    </template>
  </b-modal>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      extension: {
        namespace: '',
        localName: '',
        dataType: 'string'
      },
      showModal: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitExtension () {
      // Call vuex store to save information
      this.$store.commit('addExtension', this.extension)

      // Hide modal after submitting modal
      this.$store.commit('toggleExtensionModal')
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Following is my `ExtensionComponent.vue` which will display data recursively:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="extension in extensionList"
      :key="extension.ID"
      class="form-inline"
    >
      <span>{{ extension.namespace + ":" + extension.localName }}</span>
      <input
        v-if="extension.dataType == 'string'"
        type="text"
        @input="$emit('AddExtensionText', {$event, id: extension.ID})"
      >
      <ExtensionComponent v-if="extension.dataType == 'complex'" :extension-list="extension" @AddExtensionText="AddExtensionText($event)" />
      <button
        v-if="extension.dataType == 'complex'"
        @click="AddComplextExtension(extension.ID, extension)"
      >
        Add another
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ExtensionComponent from '@/components/ExtensionComponent.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    ExtensionComponent
  },
  props: {
    extensionList: Array,
    extension: Object
  },
  methods: {
    AddComplextExtension (extensionID, extension) {
      this.$store.commit('modules/ExtensionDataStore/showExtensionModal')
    },
    AddExtensionText ({ value, id }) {
      const i = this.extensionList.findIndex(el => el.ID === id)
      this.$set(this.extensionList, i, value)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Following is my `index.js` Vuex store:

```
export const state = () => ({
  extensionID: 0,
  extensionList: [],
  showModal: false
})

export const mutations = {
  toggleExtensionModal (state) {
    // Function to show/hide the extension Modal
    state.showModal = !state.showModal
  },
  addExtension (state, extension) {
    console.log(extension)
    extension.ID = state.extensionID
    state.extensionList.push(extension)
    state.extensionID++
  }
}

export const actions = {}
```

Following is the front-end I have:
[image]

I want to create JSON and show it something like this:
[image]

As we can see if the value is `complex` then the field is created dynamically and displayed in a parent-child relationship way. I am a bit confused about how to establish the parent-child relationship within complex JSON and show them to the user. Someone,Ad

Comment: I think you really need to focus this a bit more.  If you already have the UI working as you want, don't  include it here.  Focus on what's missing: what inputs and outputs do you have?  And include an example or two.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks for your response. I believe I have explained my issue clearly I am unable to display the data recursively as I want and I am unable to create the Dynamic data based on user input. I have also provided the reproducible code from my project. The above code and explanation are asking for help on how to create the JSON dynamically and display them as shown in the image. If you have any suggestions or code samples then it would be really helpful for me.

Comment: Perhaps I'm simply confused, but I'm not making enough sense of what you're looking for to offer any help.  It might help if you created a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992) showing what you have.  I chimed in because it sounds like you *might* have an interesting question here.  If it's about Vue and how to use Vue, I would walk away due to a lack of expertise and interest.  But if it's about dynamic representation of a data structure in JSON, I might be intrigued enough to fiddle with it.  From your question, I simply can't tell.

Comment: If it's about UI presentation, then alternating vertical and horizontal expansions are the best technique I know for this, and that's what you seem to be doing.  But you need strong borders to show the containment hierarchy.  And this technique has real limits, especially horizontally, if there are many fields at one level.  At that point, I think you're stuck with an ever more-deeply nested vertical representation.  It's not sexy, but it can get the point across.  And I'd still have full borders, although fairly light-weight, to show containment.  NB: I am not a UX guy.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Thanks a lot for your response. Based on your comments I have edited the question and added the progress I have so far. Basically, I want to create a JSON that expands horizontally and basically based on the user input and would like to show the same recursively in the front end using `Vuejs`. I have also added the code in the following link which you can run and test: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-wildflower-5f7x9?file=/pages/index.vue:0-574

Comment: @ScottSauyet If you get a chance please have a look and provide your suggestion. I hope the question is bit more clear to you this time and you can provide some suggestion or sample using which I can progress further.

Comment: I'm afraid that -- as best I can tell -- this is about Vue and its UI. And I have no expertise or interest in those.  If you have a discussion about the data structure and how to work with it, I would suggest opening another question (and ping me in the comments; I might be interested.) Note that the reason I asked for a snippet is that I, like many others am behind some corporate wall that blocks codesandbox.io and many of the others. In my case, I can see JSFiddle and Codepen, but not JSBin, CodeSandbox or Repl.it. Don't ask why! Besides a snippet often helps you focus on a single problem.